# Andengine - IEntityModifierListener not working

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am attempting to use an entity modifier to manipulate some sprites and once completed it should unregister its self. I have also added a boolean value to ensure that it is not triggered again while in motion. The problem is that the methods onModifierStarted and onModifierFinished dont seem to fire.

This is the code which sets up the entity modifier

```
entityModifier = new SequenceEntityModifier(new IEntityModifierListener() {

        @Override
        public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            enabled = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               enabled = true;
               pItem.unregisterEntityModifier((IEntityModifier) pModifier);
               pModifier.reset();
        }
    },
    new AlphaModifier(2f, 1f, 0f),
            new RotationModifier(1, 0, 90),
            new AlphaModifier(2, 1, 0),
            new AlphaModifier(1, 0, 1),
            new ScaleModifier(2, 1, 0.5f),
            new DelayModifier(0.5f),
            new ParallelEntityModifier(
                                       new ScaleModifier(3, 0.5f, 5),
                                       new RotationByModifier(3, 90)
                                       ),
                                       new ParallelEntityModifier(
                                                                new ScaleModifier(3, 5, 1),
                                                                new RotationModifier(3, 180, 0)
                                                          )
            );
```

This is the method which registers the modifier onto the sprites. This is triggered from a touch event

```
    public void down(){
    if (enabled) {
        TitleSprite.registerEntityModifier(entityModifier.deepCopy());
        OptionsButton.registerEntityModifier(entityModifier.deepCopy());
        PlayButton.registerEntityModifier(entityModifier.deepCopy()); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the deepCopy is not making a deep enough copy.

The deep copy method jsut does this:

```
return new SequenceEntityModifier(this);
```

Which will exclude your overrides of onModifierStarted and onModifierFinished.

Instead, try making a private class that extends SequenceEntityModifier and use that instead. Or create a method that you can pass in your sprites and buttons that will add an entity listener to it.